# No plugin found for prefix

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am trying to deploy a file to a remote repository using the command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file –DgroupId=io.mymetrics -DartifactId=metrics-core -Dversion=4.0.0- -Dpackaging=jar –Dfile=/Users/ssurendran/code/telemetry2/metrics/lib/mymetrics-core.jar -DrepositoryId=releases –Durl=http://maven.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/central/
```

I get this error message:
*No plugin found for prefix '–Durl=http' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/ssurendran/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]*

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is a result of unfortunate copy-pasting, but a couple of things come to mind:

- There is a dash at the end of the version flag.
- The dashes before `DgroupId`, `Dfile` and `Durl` are *long* dashes (`0xe28093`) and should be regular hyphen/minus characters (`0x2d`).

The *long* dashes will confuse `mvn` on some platforms. Just change them to hyphen/minus characters and it should work.

The reason it got stuck on the string "–Durl=http" is that it is trying to parse the entire last string as a plugin command (`<plugin>:<goal>`) and your URL includes a colon.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was due to the character used, as Daniel addresses. Thanks a lot!